# Add custom claims from stored in database on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following `ClaimsTransformer` class that works very well for assigning custom claims on startup, but I need to also be able to retrieve claims that are stored in a database and add them to the user identity. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to access the database from within this class. My assumption was that I would be able to inject my database class using DI, but I'm unable to do so because it will no longer accommodate the constructor for `IClaimsTransformation`.

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var identity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            if (identity != null)
            {
                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, identity.Name);
                if (user != null) claims.Add(new Claim(CustomClaimType.DisplayName.ToString(), user.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        claims.AddRange(identity?.Claims);

        //var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, identity?.AuthenticationType);
        var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Kerberos");
        return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the code of the [PolicyServer](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/PolicyServer.Local/AspNetCore/PolicyServerMiddleware.cs) for some inspiration. From the [code](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/Host/Startup.cs#L33):

```
// this sets up the PolicyServer client library and policy provider -
// configuration is loaded from appsettings.json
services.AddPolicyServerClient(Configuration.GetSection("Policy"))
    .AddAuthorizationPermissionPolicies();
```

reads policies from a json file, something like:

```
"Policy": {
  "claims": [
    {
      "name": "tenantid",
      "value": "44"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
```

but that can be any source. In your case it may be a singleton that is filled from the database.

And add the claims using [middleware](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/PolicyServer.Local/AspNetCore/PolicyServerMiddleware.cs#L27). In your case something like:

```
// Inject the repository
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IClaimsRepository repository)
{
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Get claims from (cached) database, singleton.
        var claims = await repository.GetClaimsAsync();
        if (claims.Count > 0)
        {
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyMiddleware", "name", "role");
            // Add as extra Identity to User.
            context.User.AddIdentity(id);
        }
    }
    await _next(context);
}
```